# Hyperledger Sawtooth Install problems on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, hyperledger, ubuntu-18.04, hyperledger-sawtooth

I was trying to install Hyperledger Sawtooth as per below link but unlike the supported 16.04 version of Ubuntu, I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS that was released earlier this month. Could you please share thoughts on how I can resolve this issue?

Warm Regards,
Rishi

```
Rishi@Explorer-Ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install -y sawtooth
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 sawtooth : Depends: python3-sawtooth-cli but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: python3-sawtooth-intkey but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: python3-sawtooth-poet-cli but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: python3-sawtooth-poet-core but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: python3-sawtooth-poet-families but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: python3-sawtooth-poet-simulator but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: python3-sawtooth-rest-api but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: python3-sawtooth-sdk but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: python3-sawtooth-settings but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: python3-sawtooth-signing but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: python3-sawtooth-validator but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: python3-sawtooth-xo but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
Rishi@Explorer-Ubuntu:~$ python3 --version
Python 3.6.5
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like Ubuntu 18.04 is not yet supported. Let us wait for Hyperledger to support it.

> android@baymax:~$ ./prereqs-ubuntu.sh
>
> Error: Ubuntu bionic is not supported

Answer (score 1):

Currently, sawtooth 1.0.x supports only 16.04 LTS. If possible, switch to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Also, you could continue using [sawtooth with dockers](https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/core/releases/latest/app_developers_guide/docker.html) or use sawtooth with ["adapt"](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/adapt) on your ubuntu bionic OS.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, switching to docker solved that. Ensure to use the docker file of [version 1.0.5](https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/core/releases/1.0.5/app_developers_guide/sawtooth-default.yaml).

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu server 18.04 is now supported but it seems that an issue still exists with the desktop version, at least the desktop version provided in the Windows Hyper-V 'quick create' gallery.

The problem is related to it using the wrong protobuf compiler version.

After much messing around I found that removing the protobuf module with :

apt remove -y python3-protobuf

caused the installation of sawtooth during the tutorial to restore the module which resolved the issue and I could then run through the whole Ubuntu tutorial from the 1.2.3 Sawtooth docs here :

https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/core/releases/1.2.3/app_developers_guide/ubuntu.html

Looking at the list of installed modules before and after didn't show anything obvious so it must be some module interdependency issue.

Comment: I don't know your specific problem, but I know that Sawtooth has always needed Protobuf version 3, while Ubuntu 16 (Xenial) packaged Protobuf version 2. The workaround was to create a special Sawtooth package for Protobuf v3 for use in Ubuntu 16 called `protobuf`. Before upgrading to Ubuntu 18, remove package `protobuf` and use the Ubuntu 18 (Bionic) packaged Protobuf, which is v3.